# How to add SSL to Python 3 without recompiling?

Tags: python3, software-uninstall

I installed Python ***3***.5.2 via .xz (which also installs Python 2 for some reason or Ubuntu comes with Py2... IDK), and there is a package I need that needs SSL to install and work.

Is there any way to add SSL to Python **3** without compiling a new copy (This is important since it's so easy to brick Ubuntu trying to uninstall Python, you know.)?

EDIT: I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit.

Comment: Ubuntu comes with both Python 2 and Python 3 by default. Why did you install Python 3 via .xz?

Comment: @edwinksl I didn't know that! Great, I might have screwed my OS.

Comment: Well I am not sure if you require a particular minor version of Python 3, so you may have good reasons to install from a `.xz` I just wanted to make sure you knew Ubuntu comes with Python 2 and 3.